# GAE serving older deleted version

Tags: google-app-engine

I have uploaded a new version on Google App Engine and have made it the default serving version. I have also deleted all older versions, but still GAE serves the older version on htttp connection while it serves newer on https connection. How to rectify it?

Comment: Dynamic or static requests?  Have you tried addressing it by `<version>-dot-<project>.appspot.com`?

Comment: It is giving with version dot but ideally it should give with myapp.appspot.com

Comment: Do you see logs for those requests? (i.e. is GAE indeed executing the older code which is supposed to be deleted?)

Comment: Also check the running instances and their start time - maybe some of them somehow survived the deletion of the corresponding version and still serve requests. If so just shutting them down should fix the issue.